# Why exactly can't beta regression deal with 0s and 1s in the response variable?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, beta-distribution, zero-inflation, beta-regression

Beta regression (i.e. GLM with beta distribution and usually the logit link function) is often recommended to deal with response aka dependent variable taking values between 0 and 1, such as fractions, ratios, or probabilities: [Regression for an outcome (ratio or fraction) between 0 and 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29038).

However, it is always claimed that beta regression cannot be used as soon as the response variable equals 0 or 1 at least once. If it does, one needs to either use zero/one-inflated beta model, or make some transformation of the response, etc.: [Beta regression of proportion data including 1 and 0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48028).

**My question is: which property of beta distribution prevents beta regression from dealing with exact 0s and 1s, and why?**

I am guessing it is that $0$ and $1$ are not in the support of beta distribution. But for all shape parameters $\alpha>1$ and $\beta>1$, both zero and one *are* in the support of beta distribution, it's only for smaller shape parameters that the distribution goes to infinity at one or both sides. And perhaps the sample data are such that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ providing best fit would both turn out to be above $1$.

Does it mean that in some cases one *could* in fact use beta regression even with zeros/ones?

Of course even when 0 and 1 are in the support of beta distribution, probability of observing exactly 0 or 1 is zero. But so is the probability to observe any other given countable set of values, so this cannot be an issue, can it? (Cf. [this comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48028/beta-regression-of-proportion-data-including-1-and-0#comment93717_48028) by @Glen_b).

$\hskip{8em}$[image: beta distribution]

In the context of beta regression, beta distribution is parameterized differently, but with $\phi=\alpha+\beta>2$ it should still be well-defined on $[0,1]$ for all $\mu$.

[image]

Comment: Interesting question! I don't have any answer besides the points already made by Kevin Wright. I guess that exact zeros and ones in probabilities are pathological cases (like in logistic regression) so are not that interesting since they should not happen.

Comment: @Tim Well, I don't know if they should or shouldn't happen, but they *do* happen quite often, otherwise people would not ask questions on how to deal with 0s and 1s in beta regression, would not write papers about 0-and-1 inflated beta models, etc. Anyway, I am still hoping for a more detailed answer than Kevin's. One should at least explain how these terms in the log-likelihood arise.

Comment: Update: it's probably because if 0 and 1 are in the support then PDF at these points is equal to zero, meaning that the likelihood of observing these values is zero. I would still like to see an answer explaining this carefully.

Comment: So, what distribution should one use then when the response variable assumes values in, say, $[0, \infty)$?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because the loglikelihood contains both $\log(x)$ and $\log(1-x)$, which are unbounded when $x=0$ or $x=1$.  See equation (4) of Smithson & Verkuilen, "[A Better Lemon Squeezer? Maximum-Likelihood Regression With Beta-Distributed Dependent Variables](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/met/11/1/54/)" (direct link to [PDF](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jay_Verkuilen/publication/7184584_A_better_lemon_squeezer_Maximum-likelihood_regression_with_beta-distributed_dependent_variables/links/09e4150e4f9e56a692000000/A-better-lemon-squeezer-Maximum-likelihood-regression-with-beta-distributed-dependent-variables.pdf)).

Comment: Thanks. Here is the [direct PDF link to the paper](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jay_Verkuilen/publication/7184584_A_better_lemon_squeezer_Maximum-likelihood_regression_with_beta-distributed_dependent_variables/links/09e4150e4f9e56a692000000/A-better-lemon-squeezer-Maximum-likelihood-regression-with-beta-distributed-dependent-variables.pdf). I can see that Eq. (4) will break down as soon as $y_i=0$ or $y_i=1$, but I still don't understand why this happens in the general scheme of things.

Comment: (+1) Amoeba, just look at the pdf: for *every* Beta distribution, the densities at $0$ and $1$ are either $0$ or $+\infty$.  In either case, the log likelihood will be undefined. Equivalently, as soon as there is a single $0$ or $1$ response, *all* values of the likelihood can be only zero, infinity, or indeterminate *and* there will be a nontrivial set of Beta parameters for which the minimum value of the likelihood is realized. Thus practical calculation is precluded and the model is not identifiable (in a severe sense).

Comment: Together with @whuber's comment (that I did not notice until now), this does answer the question. The main point is that for the parameter values I was asking about, $0$ and $1$ have zero likelihood.

Comment: @whuber The reason I got confused, is that there is probability zero to observe $0$ but there is also probability zero to observe, say, $0.5$ (let's take beta with $\alpha=\beta=2$ for concreteness). Nevertheless, $0.5$ is consistent with the model, but $0$ is not, and it's because the *likelihood* of observing $0.5$ is not zero but the likelihood of observing $0$ is...

Comment: @amoeba The likelihood depends on the probability *density*, not the probability itself.  Sometimes, one can avoid this issue either by considering each observation to include the probability of a tiny but finite (not infinitesimal) interval (determined, *e.g.*, by the precision of the measurement) or by convolving the Beta distributions with a very narrow Gaussian (which eliminates the zero and infinite densities).

Answer (score 2):

besides the fact that the reason comes in practice from the presence of $log(x)$ and $log(1-x)$, I will try to complement the answer to the question by trying to frame the underlying reason why this happens.

as a matter of fact, the beta distribution is "often used to describe the distribution of a probability value" ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Bayesian_inference)). It is the distribution of the possible tendencies $p$ of a binomial distribution, knowing the observation of $N$ independent binary draws of a random variable.

As a result, in my understanding of beta regression, 0s and 1s would intuitively correspond to (infinite) sure results.