# Winbugs beta distribution

Tags: beta-distribution, jags, bugs

I have fitted a likelihood function with a dbeta function in WinBUGs as follows

```
# likelihood
for(i in 1:n){
  FC[i] ~ dbeta(a[TREATMENT[i]], b[TREATMENT[i]]) 
}
```

FC is an R array with values between 1 and 0 (1 and 0 included). However, my model throws an error and does not work as it seems I cannot include 1s or 0s.

I heard that the Beta distribution works for data 0..1.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beta is a distribution bounded in $[0, 1]$, or $(0, 1)$, [depending on it's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution). Notice however that since it is continuous, probability of seeing exact $0$ or $1$ is zero. Moreover, log-likelihood for $0$ and $1$ is undefined and I guess this is the reason why the bounds are not included in Winbugs, since it needs to evaluate the log-likelihood.

See also [Why exactly can't beta regression deal with 0s and 1s in the response variable?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/262501/why-exactly-cant-beta-regression-deal-with-0s-and-1s-in-the-response-variable), and [Beta regression of proportion data including 1 and 0](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48028/beta-regression-of-proportion-data-including-1-and-0), and [Dealing with 0,1 values in a beta regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/dealing-with-0-1-values-in-a-beta-regression).