# One inflated beta regression with random effects using GAMLSS

Tags: r, mixed-model, beta-regression, gamlss

I am new to modelling percentage data, and I would be greatfull for some advice. I have proportion data (0,1] on a percentage of money sent by Player B to Player A. Participants received an amount of money, and could decide what percentage they will send back. I have two categorical predictors (1<sup>st</sup> with 3 factors, 2<sup>nd</sup> with 2); one continuous predictor; and one nesting factor (class). Since the data are bound between 0 and 1, I figured out that the best option would be Beta regression. I tried to use `hglm` package which fitted well, however, since the data are one-inflated (many people chose to send back the full amount), I am looking for other options.

As most appropriate seem to be `gamlss` package, which can use BEOI (Beta One Inflated) distribution. I used this code:

```
m1 <- gamlss(percent~cat1+cat2+continous, random(class), family=BEOI, data=dat, 
             mixture="gq", K=1)
```

From what I understand from package help files, this should be the simplest option. However, it produces very different results from the `hglm`command. Especially the standard errors are higher than beta coefficients, leading to non-significant results. I tried to specify other other functions in the model (e.g., `K, sigma.formula, nu.formula, mixture` etc.), but these are beyond my understanding, and I am not really sure what I did there.

I would very much appreciate any suggestions regarding either how to better specify the model, or simple explanations of `gamlss` function.

Comment: One possibility -- if you have access to zero-inflated beta regression, you could try to model how much they *don't* send back.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b, I tried your suggestion with gamlss BEZI distribution but I got the same problem. In the end I ended up transforming the data with [this formula](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/dealing-with-0-1-values-in-a-beta-regression) and using standard beta regression. This approach works fine; however, I still wonder what was wrong with the one-inflated model.