# Zero Inflated Beta Regression

Tags: zero-inflation, beta-regression

How can we check that the proportions are inflated at zero and one while using Beta Regression?

Answer (score 4):

Beta regression assumes that the predicted variable is in $(0, 1)$, so exact $0$ and $1$ are excluded from the interval. So if you have any exact zeros, beta distribution and regression would not be appropriate and you would need to use something like the [Hurdle model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurdle_model) to account for them.

You may also be interested in reading the [Dealing with 0,1 values in a beta regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/dealing-with-0-1-values-in-a-beta-regression) thread.

Comment: I somehow disagree... A hurdle model would assume a truncated Poisson/NB/Gaussian/etc. for the counts model so it would not allow for zeros either. So a hurdle model with Logistic/Beta for components should still be valid. No?

Comment: We could run a hurdle model with Logistic/Beta for components should still be valid instead of a standard Logistic/Truncated_Poisson (that is the usual).

Comment: @usεr11852 the only thing I'm saying is that the standard Bete regression model & common implementations would not work for data with exact 1 or 0.

Comment: Yes, of course, they shouldn't. But I am saying that "*Zero Inflated Beta Regression*" can be done through a hurdle model as it will naturally lend itself to Zero Inflated modelling.

Comment: I think that the name "zero-inflated beta regression" is the source of the confusion here. While in "zero-inflated Poisson" you really **add** "excess" zeros to the zeros from the Poisson distribution, the same is not true for "zero-inflated beta". As beta regression cannot accomodate any zeros - as correctly pointed out by Tim - there is nothing to **inflate**. A better name would be "hurdle" or "two-part" model when adding zeros (and/or ones) to a standard beta regression. This is straightforward as correctly pointed out by user11852.

Comment: @usεr11852 agree. I focused on the body of the question, asking about "inflated zeros in beta regression", but now I see how someone could focus more on the title of the question, than the body. Seems like the question is ambiguous. Edited for clarity.

Comment: @AchimZeileis You are too wise. Thank you. :) Tim, with you now, +1.