DHARMa residual pattern
I'm trying to model a behavior using glmmTMB with a beta distribution (as suggested in another post). My model consists of several fixed factors and two random effects (species and individual). I have already addressed the 0-1 problem by transforming the dependent variable using the following method:
Reference: Smithson, M., & Verkuilen, J. A better lemon squeezer? Maximum-likelihood regression with beta-distributed dependent variables. Psychol. Methods, 11, 54–71 (2006). DOI: 10.1037/1082-989X.11.1.54
After checking the residuals with DHARMa, I noticed the following patterns. I'm modeling several behaviors and obtain similar patterns for each. I have also run binomial GLMMs for dichotomous variables without encountering any issues.

My questions are:

How can I address these patterns in the residuals?
Am I interpreting the plot correctly? Based on my understanding, the model underestimates the residuals for low predicted values and overestimates them for high predicted values, meaning that it fails to accurately model both low and high values of the dependent variable. Am I correct, or am I misunderstanding this entirely?


Hi Dmitry, welcome to CV. Could you clarify what the "0-1 problem" is, and the solution in Smithson's paper (I don't have access to it)

Of course, and thank you for the welcome. What I mean is that the beta distribution can't handle 0s and 1s, so I had to transform the data using the following formula:
(X*(N-1)+0.5)/N
I followed the suggestion from this other post:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31300/dealing-with-0-1-values-in-a-beta-regression

My feeling is that the transformation isn't really a fix. What you're doing is stacking a heap of values around (let's say) 0.01 and 0.99. A beta distribution can't fit peaks like that, I suspect the model is struggling and so is giving a bad fit. If you have a lot of 0s or 1s, you might want to try 0-1  inflated beta regression. I am not sure if there is a package that does this in R but there is an example here https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/660#issuecomment-759873444

The zero-inflated beta model worked; now the model fits adequately. I still have outliers, but the strange pattern has disappeared. I thought the transformation could handle the inability of beta regression to deal with 0 and 1 values, but now that I know and understand zero-inflation, I see that the transformation does nothing to solve the problem.

Cool! It's more like "the transformation allows the model to fit", but it doesn't necessarily mean it'll be a good fit :P

I've posted my comment as an answer :)

The transformation isn't really a fix. What you're doing is stacking a heap of values around (let's say) 0.01 and 0.99. A beta distribution can't fit peaks like that, I suspect the model is struggling and so is giving a bad fit.
If you have a lot of 0s or 1s, you might want to try 0-1 inflated beta regression. I am not sure if there is a package that does this in R but there is an example here: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/660#issuecomment-759873444

brms has family zero_one_inflated_beta
